# If $L_\alpha \vDash ZFC$, then do we have $L_{\alpha+1} \vDash \alpha\text{ is inaccessible}$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, ordinal-numbers, constructibility

Here we choose the definition of "is a cardinal" as there is no surjective map from a smaller ordinal to it.

It's easy to prove that, if $L_{\alpha+1} \vDash\ \alpha\text{ is inaccessible}$, then $L_\alpha \vDash ZFC$. Also it's easy to prove that if $L_\alpha \vDash ZFC$, then α is a cardinal in $L_{\alpha+1}$. However, I don't know how to prove confinally many cardinals won't collapse at the next step of L.

If the answer is false, then is it true at the least such α?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. The elements of $L_{\alpha+1}$ are exactly those subsets of $L_\alpha$ which are definable from parameters over $L_\alpha$. But $L_\alpha\models\mathrm{ZFC}$, so from here we can just use the usual proof that second order ZFC implies inaccessibility. That is:

(i) every bounded subset of $L_\alpha$ which is in $L_{\alpha+1}$, is already in $L_\alpha$, and so $L_{\alpha+1}$ agrees with $L_\alpha$ regarding power sets and cardinalities of elements of $L_\alpha$; that is, for each $x\in L_\alpha$, we have $\mathcal{P}(x)^{L_{\alpha+1}}=\mathcal{P}(x)^{L_\alpha}$, and $\mathrm{card}(x)^{L_{\alpha+1}}=\mathrm{card}(x)^{L_\alpha}$;  in particular, $L_{\alpha+1}\models$"$\alpha$ is a strong limit cardinal", and

(ii) for every $\beta<\alpha$ and every $f:\beta\to\alpha$ which is in $L_{\alpha+1}$, $f$ is bounded in $\alpha$; that is, $L_{\alpha+1}\models$"$\alpha$ is regular".

Comment: I think that for the least such $\alpha$, the $\Sigma_1$ projectum of $L_{\alpha+1}$ is $\omega$, but I don'tcknow how to prove it. Could you tell me how to prove it?

Comment: The 1st standard parameter of $L_{\alpha+1}$ is also $\{\alpha\}$. Thus, $L_{\alpha+1}$ is the $\Sigma_1$-hull in $L_{\alpha+1}$ of the parameter $\alpha$. You can see this by observing that $L_\alpha$ is pointwise definable; that is, for every $x\in L_\alpha$, there is a formula $\varphi$ such that $L_\alpha\models$"$x$ is the unique $y$ such that $\varphi(y)$". (This follows from condensation.) The arbitrary definitions $\varphi$ over $L_\alpha$ convert to $\Sigma_1$ over $L_{\alpha+1}$ from parameter $\alpha$.

Comment: How to use condensation to prove that x is definable? I understand that the skolem hull of empty set in $L_\alpha$ is isomorphic to $L_\alpha$. If this isomorphism is identity, then x is definable. But what if the isomorphism is not identity?

Comment: It is the identity. Suppose it's not. By condensation, the hull of $L_\alpha$ collapses to some $L_\beta$ with $\beta\leq\alpha$, and we get $\pi:L_\beta\to L_\alpha$ the uncollapse map, which is elementary. $L_\beta$ is moreover pointwise definable, because it was the collapse of the definable hull. But $L_\beta\models$ ZFC, so by minimality of $\alpha$, $\beta=\alpha$. So $L_\alpha$ is pointwise definable, so actually $\pi$ is the identity.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made a very foolish mistake, I didn't realize that since π is elementary, a definition of π(x) is also a definition of x (and this step is all that I was lacking of).